# jQuery .each() function. Resetting the index?

Tags: jquery

I have multiple lists with the same class.

I'd like to loop each list and its LI's and prepend the current number before each. The current code I have is:

```
$jQuery(".numberList li").each(function(i) {

    var index = i + 1;

    $jQuery(this).prepend("<span>" + index + "</span>");

});
```

The problem is, is that the index doesn't restart back at 0 for each list it goes through, it just keeps going up. For example, the output I get now is:

```
First list
1. item
2. item
3. item

Second list
4. item
5. item
6. item
```

Second list should start at 1 again by having the index back at 0.

Could someone point out where I'm going wrong? I'm not a jQuery expert or anything...clearly :)

Many thanks,
Michael.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615758/using-each-method-how-do-i-get-the-indexes-of-multiple-ordered-lists-to-each

Comment: Thanks for the link. I did have a search but couldn't think of the right terms to get a good result. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

I'd think about nesting loops.

Something like:

```
$('.numberList').each(function(){
   $this.children('li').each(function(i){
      var index = i + 1;
      $jQuery(this).prepend("<span>" + index + "</span>");
   });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not use just stylesheets?

```
.numberList {
    list-style-type: decimal;
}
```

You can apply this style through jQuery if for some reason it has to be done dynamically:

```
$(".numberList").css("list-style-type", "decimal");​
```

An [example here](http://jsfiddle.net/pCecH/1/).